# Regular crash / freeze Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, freeze

I work uninterruptedly for 8-10 hours a day, and every single day the system completely freezes - mouse, keyboard, music, videos and anything running stops. After a minute or 2, the system gradually returns with some intermittent breaks until normal operation is reached after about 5 minutes. An error message appears with the option of send system crash log - what I always do.

There is no apparent pattern triggering the crash. 
My system log before and after the crash is [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24468729/). I'm not advanced user, so there isn't any identifiable clue in this log for me. Any advise will be appreciated.

System info:

- Memory 7.7 GiB
- Processor Intel Core i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz x 4
- Graphics Intel Haswell Mobile
- OS type 64-bit
- Disk 903 GB (43% used)

Comment: I just want to say that I see this as well on my Ubuntu server. Even cron jobs that need to run every minute simply get delayed, and after a few minutes all is well again. I am very curious if anyone can spot something wrong here.

Comment: Today, 10:30 ( another crash). The log [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24473630/), this time few lines what I think represent the log of the system crash.

Comment: The crash behavior continues over and over again.  Most times now, the system doesn't show any crash until I click on calendar or shutdown button in the panel. It really weird. If someone has any clue, please report.

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing this issue for a while. This could be due to the system running out of memory when there are too many processes going on. 
This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/942629) might help you which talks about increasing RAM and SWAP.
Increasing SWAP size worked for me as I have not experienced freezes lately.

```
# sudo swapon -s
# sudo swapoff /swapfile 
# sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile

# sudo mkswap /swapfile
# sudo swapon /swapfile
# sudo swapon -s
```